# Decimal to Float conversion issue in C#

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion, decimal

Can anyone please help me with this problem?

I have in the database a nullable "real" column that Entity Framework represents as "float?"

The system does some calculations in decimal but when assigns the value in this column the precision is lost.

The system is using the next conversion:

```
dbObject.floatCol = (float) decimalVar;
```

decimalVar is = 123.12341

but dbObject.floatCol is = 123.1234

I been trying to do this convertion in other ways without luck.

NOTES:

1. In the database I can update the value to 123.12341 without problem.
2. I can't alter the database's column
3. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with .NET Framework 4

EDIT:
If I debug the problem (with the real numbers of my issue) I have:

```
decimal decimalVar = new decimal(123.13561);
// decimalVar is 123.13561
float? floatVar = 0;
// floatVar is 0
floatVar = (float)decimalVar;
// floatVar is 123.135612 <- has appeared a 2 at the end

// with a different decimal number
decimalVar = new decimal(128.13561); // replaced the 123 for 128
// decimalVar is 128.13561
floatVar = (float)decimalVar;
// floatVar is 128.1356 <- has disappeared the 1 at the end
```

The behavior is really weird
I need to know if is possible to do a correct conversion
When I try to print the values to Console or Logfile they are different :s

Comment: The type mapping between C# and SQLServer can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting about 7 digits precision. This is what you can expect from a C# [`float`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx). If you need more precision, use a C# [`double`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) value instead. It gives you about 15 to 16 digits precision.

```
double d = (double)decimalVar;
```

An also you must make a difference between the C# data types and the database data types. In C#, the best data type for reading in a db `decimal` column is [`decimal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx).

Depending on the database type, different names are used for the numeric column types. And those names are different from the C# types. A SQL-Server `float` corresponds to a C# `double`. A SQL-Server `real` corresponds to a C# `float` (.NET `Single`).

See: [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx)

Concerning your EDIT: `float` and `double` values have a binary representation as a floating point number internally which requires decimal numbers to be rounded to the closest possible matching binary value. This binary value is then converted back to a decimal representation for display. Depending on whether the value was rounded up or down this might add or remove decimals. This is what you experienced.

See Jon Skeet's article on [Binary floating point and .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I have no other choice than change the database type.
Weird thing is: I can update the value in the database to 123.12341, and I can define a float var = 123.12341f, but cann't do the conversion from decimal to float correctly.

Comment: It also depends on the formatting used. Mabe the number still has the last `1` stored, but it is not displayed by default. Try display the converted value by specifying the digits explicitly: `x.ToString("0.000000")`.

Comment: @MiguelValdes: You can define a literal float with a lot more precision in code than the number will actually hold. If you output the results of `123.12341f`, you'll see it's still just `123.1234`.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior that explains the strange behavior. Thanks!